# In Django/Python, how to, after proper validation, insert a field data in the database formatted as desired?

Tags: django, model, admin, customvalidator

I'm developing a web system with Django/Python and I need a specific field from the User model: **CPF** ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_de_Pessoas_Físicas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_de_Pessoas_F%C3%ADsicas)). I need it with a validator and to be properly formatted before insertion in the the database.

I've tried to use `localflavor.br.forms.BRCPFField` from `django-localflavor` and `django-localflavor-br` (https://django-localflavor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/localflavor/br/), but `makemigrations` couldn't recognize the new field neither `migrate` could update the respective table in the database (I think it's a bug, but this issue is not for now). So, after considering other options, I've decided to give it a try and to write my own validator.

**EDIT 1:** Code corrected as mentioned in my comment to Daniel's answer.

In `models.py`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_cpf(cpf):
    digitos = [int(digit) for digit in cpf if digit.isdigit()]
    if len(digitos) < 11 or len(digitos) > 11:
        raise ValidationError("Wrong number of digits")
    sop = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(digitos[0:9], range(10, 1, -1)))
    ed1 = (sop * 10 % 11) % 10
    sop = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(digitos[0:10], range(11, 1, -1)))
    ed2 = (sop * 10 % 11) % 10
    if ed1 != digitos[9] or ed2 != digitos[10]:
        raise ValidationError("Verification digits don't match")
    else:
        numeros = ''.join(str(d) for d in digitos)
        return f'{numeros[0:3]}.{numeros[3:6]}.{numeros[6:9]}-{numeros[9:]}'

class Usuario(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14, validators=[validate_cpf])
```

In `admin.py`:

```
from .models import Usuario

class UsuarioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [ ('ID', { 'fields': ['name', 'cpf', ], }), ]
    list_display = ('name', 'cpf', )

admin.site.register(Usuario, UsuarioAdmin)
```

When in administration area (http://localhost:8000/admin/), I can add a new User without problems. The written validator also works fine:

1. `23755124050` is accepted.
2. `237.551.240-50` is accepted.
3. `+-*23755124050` or some other imaginable string with those 11 digits in this particular order is accepted.
4. `237.551.240-51` is not accepted : *("Verification digits don't match")*
5. `37.551.240-50` is not accepted : *("Wrong number of digits")*

So, validator works fine.

**EDIT 2:** Text corrected following first edit.

The problem is, when I save it to the database, I want -- no matter the input case (1) to (3) -- to save it formatted as: `f'{numeros[0:3]}.{numeros[3:6]}.{numeros[6:9]}-{numeros[9:]}'`. But the database always save the input text as given before validation (considering the input text as validated). So `+-*23755124050` is saved as it is, not as `237.551.240-50` the way I intend of.

This is tricky for me, I'm missing something important in this process. Could anybody enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use a validator, you should use a custom form with a `clean_cpf` method; this has the dual responsibility of validating the input, and returning the data in the form you want to store it. (Note, inside a clean method you need to raise `forms.ValidationError`, not `core.exceptions.ValidationError`).

```
class MyUsarioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_cpf(self):
        cpf = self.cleaned_data['cpf']
        digitos = [int(digit) for digit in cpf if digit.isdigit()]
        if len(digitos) < 11 or len(digitos) > 11:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong number of digits")
        sop = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(digitos[0:9], range(10, 1, -1)))
        ed1 = (sop * 10 % 11) % 10
        sop = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(digitos[0:10], range(11, 1, -1)))
        ed2 = (sop * 10 % 11) % 10
        if ed1 != digitos[9] or ed2 != digitos[10]:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Verification digits don't match")
        else:
            return f'{digitos[0:2]}.{digitos[3:5]}.{digitos[6:8]}-{digitos[9:10]}'


class UsuarioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UsarioForm
```

Comment: I got it wrong in my code, please correct `return f'{digitos[0:2]}.{digitos[3:5]}.{digitos[6:8]}-{digitos[9:10]}'` to `numeros = ''.join(str(d) for d in digitos), return f'{numeros[0:3]}.{numeros[3:6]}.{numeros[6:9]}-{numeros[9:]}'`. Thanks for your insight!